# How to access (i+1 ) index in the second for loop in the below case?

Tags: python, pandas

The train is a data frame in which I have two columns:

```
  Address   gender
0 abc        f
1 dfg        m
2 hjk        m
3 ert        m
```

when genders are the same I need to perform some operation on the address column so I am using this code moreover I am new to python and pandas so I don't know if I am doing it correctly and efficiently.

```
for i in train.index:
    for j in train.index[i+1]:
        
        if train.loc[i,'gender']== train.loc[j,'gender']:
            print(train['Address'])
```

currently, this code is giving an error:

```
'int' object is not iterable
```

can anyone please help me solve this issue?

Comment: Share the full code.

Comment: And which line is the error

Comment: second for loop line

Comment: You shouldn't be using pandas like this to begin with.

Comment: then how should i use could you please help me?

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30673503/11261546) might be the one

Comment: avoid for loops in pandas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that you are having is because the `train.index[i+1]` is not interable. It is an integer.

Why you don't use `.shift` instead using the second loop?

```
for i in train.index:
    if train.loc[i,'gender']== train['gender'].shift(-1)[i]:
        print(train['Address'])
```

Just to remember, the line `print(train['Address'])` will print all the `'Address'` Column. If you want the specific `'Address'` when your conditional is `True` you should use `print(train['Address'][i])`