# add values from another column from next row to update values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the one below:

```
           a         b  
  0       420        50
  1       380        40
  2       390        45
```

The problem is that I want to update column 'a' by using the first value (420) and adding the value from column 'b' but the next row and update as it goes through so the final data frame will look like this:

```
           a         b  
  0       420        50
  1       460        40
  2       505        45
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas compare next row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30673209/pandas-compare-next-row)

Comment: `.shift` seems to be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.assign(a=df['b'].cumsum() + 420 - 50)
```

output:

```
    a   b
0   420 50
1   460 40
2   505 45
```

`df.loc[0, 'a']` can replace 420 , `df.loc[0, 'b']` can replace 50